# How to print out to a file using Standford Classifier

Tags: classification, nlp, supervised-learning

I am using [Standford Classifier](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/classifier.shtml) for my project.
This project takes training data to tune the algorithm then test data to classify text inputs into categories.

So the format for test and training data is tab-delimited text which means predictor `-TAB- input text`

The software prints out the output to `stdout` (command line).
Is there anyway to output to a text file?

I searched the [javadoc](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/classify/ColumnDataClassifier.html) of the project site, and I found:

[image: this one]

But I don't know how to use this property.

I tried `-csvoutput=%1%n%c` on command line
But it gives me java null pointer exception error when I try to run it.
Any ideas?
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have experience with Stanford Classifier, but if it is sending output to stdout that you would like to capture, you can simply pipe the output to a file. You didn't mention an OS, but on most the `>` operator is used to redirect `stdout` to a file.

For example, if you are running Standard Classifier like this:

```
java -cp stanford-classifier.jar [option...]
```

You can instead run it like this to output to a file:

```
java -cp stanford-classifier.jar [option...] > my-output.tsv
```